# A better way to implement undo deletion

Tags: android, list, undo

I'm currently developing an Android app, and I have an activity with a list and a database for its contents. There is an undo feature provided: when user deletes an entry, a popup `Item deleted. Undo?` appears. That's how it's impemented: user deletes it only on the screen, no changes to the database are made. Only when the popup disappears (or the activity is to be closed), the entry is removed from database.

The question is: would it be better to remove deleted entry from database instantly and then add it back when user wants to undo deletion? Or, maybe, would be better to make all the changes to database only when user leaves the activity? Why, if so?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not a question that deserves negative votes, but I personally like the idea of waiting for the user action to do any DB operations as it's definitely costlier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best approach is usually to ask whether the user really wants to delete it and delete it when confirmed.

The undo approach can be simply implemented by marking the row in the database as deleted and really delete it after the pop-up is closed or when the application (re)starts. You can then simply ignore all marked-for-deletion rows in all queries as well.

Comment: [This Android Developers page](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/confirming-acknowledging.html) has a good flowchart which tells whether to ask user before doing some action or to provide an undo option after doing it, so I decided to make it properly (My way through the chart was 1 - No → 2 - Yes → 3 - Yes → Yes, which tells to make an undo option). Your vision of undo approach looks almost the same as mine, so I think I'm gonna keep it as it is. Thanks.

Comment: @Kotenko: deletion falls under Unrecoverable data loss in 1 so your answer to 1 should be yes

Comment: Hm, yeah, you're right. Looks like every Google's app which provides an undo deletion feature, moves entry to trash folder if not undone, so the user can recover it easily anyway. Thanks for correcting as well.